# To declare a variable a member of a set, must it be able to take on all values of that set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand what is necessary and sufficient to declare that a variable is a member of a set.

Is it the case that for a variable to a member of a set, it must be able to take on all values of that set or simply take on at least one value of that set?

Comment: If you specify that $x\in A$ and making no other unjustified claims or assumptions about $x$, and you prove that $x$ must satisfy some property, then you will have in effect proven that *every* element in $A$ satisfies that property.

Comment: Now... if you have reason to, you can give more qualifications about $x$.  For example "*Let $x\in \Bbb N$ such that $x$ is a multiple of $3$.*"  In that example, there are very explicitly some elements of $\Bbb N$ which $x$ cannot be, for example $5$, however $x$ can be any element of the set which satisfies all of the stated assumptions or requirements.

Comment: Lets say $ omega \in $ ''the set of positive integers that end in a 3''. Is it also true to say $ omega \in \mathbb{N} $ without further qualification?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "numbers" and what you mean by "end in a 3."  I consider $2.03$ to be a number and I also consider it to end in a $3$, but I do not consider it to be a natural number.  At the same time though, I don't know that I consider $2.02999999\dots$ to "end in a 3" when written in that form despite them being equal, so if you were allowing real numbers then I would clarify that they be represented without repeating nines to avoid the confusion caused by the fact that real numbers have multiple representations.

Comment: As per your edit in your comment, yes, stating that $x$ is a positive integer that ends in a $3$, this implies that $x\in \Bbb N$.  The reverse implication is of course untrue.

Comment: Mathematics is all about being precise, and knowing exactly what we’re talking about. In this context, I don’t know what you mean by a “variable”.